# Передача событий из диалогового окна обратно во фрагмент

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, dialogfragment

День добрый. Использую пример с сайта https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents чтоб передать событие по нажатию кнопки диалога обратно в активити. В активити все работает без пробем, но когда я заменил все на фрагменты. Начинаются проблемы. Фрагмент, который вызывал диалог не принимает событие. Более того приложение крашится на вызове диалога на строке создания `public interface timerButtonListener` вот код:

```
 public interface timerButtonListener{
    public void positive (DialogFragment dialogFragment);
}
timerButtonListener tbl;
public void onAttach (Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        tbl=(timerButtonListener) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
    }
}
```

Принимаю во фрагменте:

```
public class ProcessFragment extends Fragment implements TimerDialog.timerButtonListener{
//...
@Override
public void positive(DialogFragment dialogFragment) {

}
```

Возможно ли во фрагмент передавать данные из диалога?

UPD
удалось принять в активити, где хранятся объекты. Теперь вопрос как отдать данные во фрагмент, который уже запущен

Comment: Крашится потому что слушатель = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наткнулся на Хабрахабре на [такой пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/259805/). Работает отлично.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment dialogFragmentTimer = new TimerDialog();
            bundleTime = new Bundle();
            bundleTime.putString("otd", otd);
            dialogFragmentTimer.setArguments(bundleTime);
            dialogFragmentTimer.setTargetFragment(ProcessFragment.this, 1);
            dialogFragmentTimer.show(getFragmentManager(), "timer");
        }
```

В момент вызова диалога использую `dialogFragmentTimer.setTargetFragment(ProcessFragment.this, 1);`
Далее в `onClick` диалога

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(re, true);
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            dismiss();
        }
```

И в заключение во фрагменте после `return viewPrcessFragment;`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        m = Integer.parseInt(nPod);
        m = ++m;
        nPod = String.valueOf(m);
        textViewPod.setText(nPod);
    }
}
```

Оставлю это тут, вдруг кому пригодится.

Comment: ну вот, из мухи сделали слона)) зачем?

Answer (score 1):

В диалоге вам нужно создать свой слушатель и метод его инициализирующий:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private CDFListener listener;
    public interface CDFListener {
        void action(String data);
    }

    public void setDialogListener(CDFListener listener) {
         this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Viev v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_items, container, false);

        Button b = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if (listener != null) {
                   // Отправим какие-то данные из диалога
                   String data = "example data";
                   listener.action(data);
               } else {
                   System.out.println("DialogListener == null");
               }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState); dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Далее во `Fragment`:

```
CustomDialogFragment df = new CustomDialogFragment();
df.setDialogListener(new CustomDialogFragment.CDFListener () {
    @Override
    public void action(String data) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Или Java 8+:

```
CustomDialogFragment df = new CustomDialogFragment();
df.setDialogListener(data -> {
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: Увы, listener так же null

Comment: ну я надеюсь вы удалили весь свой код из примера и оставили только этот вариант? если выполнили "Далее во Fragment" то слушатель никак не может быть null

Comment: да, создал новое диалоговое окно по вашему пример, вызывал и принимал его во фрагмент так же как вы написали. И даже с условиями все равно IDE пишет листенер нул и падает все

Comment: что значит вызывал и принимал его во фрагмент? без полной модели вашего фрагмента я уже не могу вам ничего сказать. Вы создаете окно в активности, а слушатель инициализируете во фрагменте?

Comment: нет, в активити есть фрагмент, который вызывает диалог, когда я нажимаю кнопку диалога, фрагмент должен принять ответ и отобразить это в текствью. Нашел другое рабочее решение, сейчас приложу его